# I have a Certificate of Entitlement of Abode in the UK endorsed in my SA passport. Do I need a Schengen visa to travel to Europe?

Tags: visas, schengen, south-african-citizens

I have a valid Certificate of Entitlement of Abode in the UK attached to my SA passport. Do I need a Schengen visa to travel to Europe?

Comment: The [French embassy to the UK has a page on if you need a visa](http://www.ambafrance-uk.org/Do-you-need-a-visa), do any of the entries in the `Holders of passports and other travel documents issued by the British authorities` section apply to you?

Comment: British nationality law is very complex but how is that possible exactly? Could you provide more details on you status?

Answer (score 1):

You will still need a Schengen visa to travel to Europe as it is the Issuing Country of your Passport that will be taken into account and not any endorsements that you have inside it.

Comment: I tend to think so too but there are some special rules for British nationals who are not British citizens. Is it possible to get an endorsement without having some sort of British nationality?

Comment: The Certificate of Entitlement to the Right of Abode in the UK, entitles a person to live and work in the United Kingdom without restriction. It is specifically for entry into the UK and cannot be used to enter other European Schengen member destiantions

Comment: Yes that's clear but it does also exempt some British subjects, British nationals (overseas) and some other categories of British nationals from the visa requirement for short visits to the Schengen area. It might not apply to the OP however, hence my question.

Comment: Definitely need a Schengen visa unless you fall into one of the following categories (Which a Certificate of Entitlement of Abode is not one of them) BRITISH CITIZENS WHO ARE NOT NATIONALS OF THE UNITED KINGDOM OF GREAT BRITAIN AND NORTHERN IRELAND FOR THE PURPOSES OF UNION LAW: British nationals (Overseas), British overseas territories citizens (BOTC) British overseas citizens (BOC) British protected persons (BPP) and British subjects (BS)’. REGULATION (EU) No 509/2014 OF THE EUROPEAN PARLIAMENT AND OF THE COUNCI

Comment: I am confused. The change you found (which I didn't know about) means that British nationals don't need a visa anymore, making my question even more relevant.

Comment: If you check the  [last consolidated version](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02001R0539-20140428), you will see that until now, British overseas territories citizens and British subjects did need a visa, except if they had the right of abode.

Comment: British nationals have never needed a visa to enter a Schengen member country. I am a British national and in the last 30 years have travelled to France, Spain, Italy, Belgium, Denmark, Croatia, Greece without one - simply because I don't need one as a British National. Anyway this is digressing from the original issue. You will need a Schengen visa if your South African Passport has a Certificate of entitlement of Adobe

Comment: Some did, per the regulation you just quoted!

Comment: The point that confused me is whether South African nationals can get a certificate of entitlement of abode without also being British nationals. It might be a very basic question, due to my lack of understanding of British nationality law but all the digressions did nothing to clarify that point for me.